# How to change adminer's default port?

Tags: webserver, debian, database

My Adminer (Database management in a single PHP file) runs on a Debian Server, and I want to move my database management web login screen from port 80 to port 50001. 
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 4):

The correct question would be: **How to change my web server's default port?**

In case you're using Apache Web Server, then follow this steps:

In `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, change the port to:

```
Listen 50001
```

Then go to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

And change the first line to:

```
<VirtualHost *:50001>
```

Now restart the apache2 service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Apache will now listen on port 50001.

Comment: But how to change the port when using `docker run --network host adminer` ?

Comment: Why change the default listen port for the default site/IP? Just create your own apache virtual host file with same.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are using an Apache web server. You did not say

If you downloaded/installed the website (https://www.adminer.org/) version:

- You are probably already using it with an Apache "site" file (such as
  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/adminer.conf). Just update the
  `/etc/apache2/ports` file and your first `VirtualHost` port line as
  in other answer.
- Note: *It is better to use a custom site file - not the default (000-default.conf) site file* as per other answer.

---

But, it sounds like questioner/OP installed the **Debian "apt"/repo version** of adminer:

In this case, you will have to disable the `adminer.conf` file and recreate the disabled file with your own Apache virtual site file (not the default one) that also listens on the port specified. That way, *just adminer* is on port 50001 - not the entire IP as in other answer:

1. Disable the 'conf' file installed/enabled:
   `sudo a2disconf adminer`
2. Add a `listen 50001` statement here (as on other answer):
   `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`
3. Create an Apache site file:

   `/etc/apache2/sites-available/adminer.conf`:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:50001>
     ServerName localhost
     Alias /adminer /etc/adminer

     <Directory /etc/adminer>
       Require all granted
       DirectoryIndex conf.php
     </Directory>

     DocumentRoot /usr/share/adminer

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/adminer.error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/adminer.access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Enable site and restart: `sudo a2ensite adminer.conf && sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Only adminer will be available on that port, now.
URL: http://[yourserverip]:50001/adminer